# Data class init function is not called when object generated from GSON in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I'm using `Gsson` to convert `JSON to Kotlin data class`. While creating data class object I want to parse the value in `init` method. But `init` never called and generated object's values are null.

```
data class Configuration (val groupId:Int, val key:String, val source:String){
    val query:String
    val search:String
    init {
        val obj = JSONObject(key)
        query = obj.getString("q")
        search = obj.getString("search")
    }
}
```

When I got the object of Configuration from `Gson`, `query` and `search` value is always `null` and `init` block was never executed. I also tried `constructor` and without `data` keyword, results are same.

Comment: are you sure that you have "q" and "search" elements inside your JSONObject during initialization?

Comment: It can be GSON that overwrites these fields while deserialization. 
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Comment: @laughter Yes, key field contains a json object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`init` block is only executed when primary constructor is called. But `gson` doesn't call primary constructor when parsing json to object.

To solve this, I think, you should implement `query` and `search` as a get method or use lazy init. Something like this:

```
data class Configuration(val groupId: Int, val key: String, val source: String) {
    var query: String = ""
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                initInternal()
            }
            return field
        }
        private set

    var search: String? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                initInternal()
            }
            return field
        }
        private set

    private fun initInternal() {
        val obj = JSONObject(key)
        query = obj.getString("q")
        search = obj.getString("search")
    }
}
```

or any other approach which will suite best to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, your way works, just need to add filed != null check. Please update the answer, I'm marking it as correct answer.

Comment: @shantanu, there's no need to add a not `null` check since this variables aren't `nullable` :)

Comment: But filed.isEmptry() is getting null pointer, because initially query or search is empty (null)

Comment: @shantanu, I see, edited my answer